# How can I create multiple threads using a loop in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I was making a loop to be able to create as many threads as I want without having to write too many lines.
My first loop to start my threads works :

```py
i = 0
    tab = []
    for i in range(3):
        tab.append(i)
    
    for idx,i in enumerate(tab):
        test = "th%s"%i
        print(test , "start")
        test = InseeThreadTreatment(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DATABASE, QUEUE)
        test.start()
```

but once I get to the second to join the threads I get an error.

```py
 for idx,i in enumerate(tab):
        print(str("th%s"%i))
        str("th%s"%i).join()
```

Here is my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\me\Documents\CODE_SIREN\gestion_siren\script.py", line 50, in <module>
    test.join()
TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @TedKleinBergman probably join thread number i

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yes, this is sort of a "variable-variables" question, but with the addition that the variables `th1s`, `th2s`, ... don't even exist in OP's code.

Comment: If you want `.join()` you should look up the documentation. But did you want string formatting?

Comment: Have you thought about what the error you're getting actually means?  It's unclear how the two pieces of code you posted relate to each other, or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Anentropic Yes I just understood my error ^^ and I tried to correct it... But my problem now is that my loop remains blocked at my first join
`for idx,i in enumerate(tab_th): tab_th[idx].join()`

Comment: Seems like the problem is in `InseeThreadTreatment` then

Answer (score 0):

```py
i = 0
    tab = []
    tab_th = []
    for i in range(3):
        tab.append(i)

    for idx,i in enumerate(tab):
        test = "th%s"%i
        print(test , "start")
        test = InseeThreadTreatment(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DATABASE, QUEUE)
        test.start()
        tab_th.append(test)

    i = 0
    for idx,i in enumerate(tab_th):
        tab_th[idx].join()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).